Dirac's Bracket Notation
I have a question on Dirac's bracket notation. In particular, according to this notation, vectors and covectors are represented by $|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi|$ respectively. Moreover, these two representations are related by $|\psi\rangle^\dagger=\langle\psi|$ in a complex vector space. However, if $|\psi\rangle$ is a vector and $\langle\psi|$ is a covector, what can we say about $\psi$ on its own? What does it represent? It's neither a vector nor a covetor, but both at the same time. I've personally called $\psi$ a "mathematical vector" to distinguish it from $|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi|$ that for me are just two representations of $\psi$ that are possible once a basis for the vector space has been fixed.

It seems like $psi$ is just your label for the particular state. It has no meaning until you give it one, as you haven’t specified what object you are referring to yet.

For a related discussion, see e.g. this. I also second Valter's comment.

Indeed, what symbol or set of symbols we put inside a bra or ket is usually a label. Sometimes the label is arbitrary; sometimes it is a set of good quantum numbers, e.g. $n,l,m$ for the hydrogen atom.

In this notation, $\psi$ has no meaning.

@Tobias I removed my aggressive comment, but my opinion remains unchanged, I still remember the infinite discussions when I was student about insignificant issues like $a|\psi\rangle = |a\psi\rangle$ ?

@ValterMoretti I did not find it aggressive, and I share the opinion. From my (limited) teaching experience, the bra-ket notation adds another, unnecessary complication when students first experience Quantum Mechanics. They sometimes even think it is necessary, and create all sorts of mysteries about it.  I remember asking myself how it can be that the adjoint of the ket is the bra--we defined adjoint only for operators...and so on.

Thanks for your answers. Forgetting now about quantum mechanics and speaking only from the linear algebra viewpoint, in my idea $\psi$ could represent the abstract mathematical object which is the geometric vector, as an invariant object. On the other hand, $|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi|$ can be defined only after we've fixed a basis for the vector space. They then represent different types of operations that are duable with the mathematical vector $\psi$ that itself cannot be used in mathematical calculations since is pure abstract...

@Falcy87 No. In the "standard" Dirac-notation, $|\psi\rangle$ is a vector! You don't have to specify a basis! Also, $\langle \psi|$ is a (continuous) linear functional, i.e. an element of the (topological) dual space. You also don't need a basis.

@TobiasFünke Yes of course we agree on the fact that $|\psi\rangle$ is a vector in the proper sense of the term and that $\langle\psi|$ is a covector (or a linear functional). But what can we say about $\psi$ at this point? From the linear algebra perspective, what does $\psi$ represent?

Nothing. It is like asking what $v$ means if you denote vectors by $\vec v$. This is, I assume, what @MattHanson meant with their comment at the very beginning.

@TobiasFünke My question is not about notation, but about the intrinsic structure of things. Here $\psi$ denotes either the vector $|\psi\rangle$ either the covector $\langle\psi|$. But now, if we take another "object-to-define" $\phi$ then we can constitute its associated vector $|\phi\rangle$ and covector $\langle\phi|$ and form the operations $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|$. The same does not apply with a vector $v$ as you say, because $v$ is an element of a vector space where an algebra is well defined: from a math viewpoint we know exactly what is a vector.

@TobiasFünke To be more precise, a vector $v$ is an element of a vector space (as well as a covector), regardless of the notation that we use to represent it. In other words, we know exactly what a vector is: an element of a vector space. However, $\psi$, $\phi$ here are they elements of some vector space? It seems they're not. However, $|\psi\rangle$, $|\phi\rangle$, $\langle\psi|$ and $\langle\phi|$ are formally all vectors (as elements of the vector spaces $V$ and $V^*$). But $\psi$, $\phi$ seems to be even more abstract objects that can behave either as vectors either as covectors.

@Falcy87 sorry, but in my honest view and on the ground of my experience, yours are exactly the useless and misleading issues arising from a dangerous notation. It might have some reason to exist when notions like Hilbert space and dual space were novelties in the conceptual background of a theoretical physicist (80 years ago). Nowadays they are the standard and this  cumbersome relic, a fossil, generates conceptual monsters…stopping the comprehension of clear theoretical notions.
